# Is the logic behind `Asyncio.wait()` and async/await, the same, just the code is written differently (syntax)?

Tags: python, async, asynchronous-programming, python-3.x, parallel-programming

I'm learning Python, more specially parallel programming using [Python Parallel Programming Cookbook by Giancarlo Zaccone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1785289586).

At the time the book was published [async/await](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) was still in the beta version of Python, and so, the book doesn't cover it. It covers Asyncio. Now with the release of Python 3.5, async/await has been implemented in Python.

What are the differences between `Asyncio.wait()` and async/await? Is it just a syntax difference?

Comment: @RobertHarvey is asyncio.wait the same as using async and wait?

Comment: On your deleted question on Stack Overflow, someone commented: *"async/await does not replace the asyncio module; nearly everything the book will teach you is still relevant for 3.5, only some details of syntax have changed."*

Comment: I've cleaned up this question to make it appropriate for Programmers. I think that we can address the conceptual differences, if any, between these two approaches. It appears to be a well-written and on-topic question for us in its current form.

Answer (score 2):

See [this excellent blog post](https://snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5/). In brief, `asyncio` is an event loop library (introduced in 3.4) that's focused on I/O, and largely on networking in particular. It introduced the `asyncio.coroutine` decorator to let you identify generators meant to be used as coroutines. In any generator, you can `yield from` any other generator (or coroutine).

In 3.5 the keywords `async` and `await` were introduced. You can only `await` inside an `async` function, and you can only `await` on a coroutine or `Awaitable`. You cannot `await` a general generator, and you cannot use `yield` or `yield from`. This helps protect against accidentally using a generator as a coroutine.

`async` and `await` are general enough to be used with any event loop provider, and `asyncio` happens to be one.